# Is there any way to make a custom keyboard shortcut that copy something to clipboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I am trying to find a way to create a keyboard shortcut that copy a specific string to the clipboard every time I call it. Is there away to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `xsel`:

```
sudo apt install xsel
```

Go to settings, Keyboard, add a new shortcut like:

```
sh -c 'echo [your string here] | xsel -bi'
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know the command to paste?

Comment: To paste into `stdout` you can use: `xsel -o`. in other applications simply use `ctrl`+`v` as you always do ;)

Comment: thanx xsel -o worked perfect for me

Comment: Glad that it was helpful :)

Comment: You might want to use `echo -n` if you don't want to include a trailing newline on your text.